# Postgres - ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY Position: 305

Tags: postgresql

Having a little trouble with a query provided by Periscope.  Can you help point me in the right direction?

Error is - ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY Position: 305

```
with monthly_activity as (
  select distinct
    date_trunc('month', created_at) as month,
    user_id
  from oauth_refresh_tokens
), 
first_activity as (
  select user_id, date(min(created_at)) as month
  from oauth_refresh_tokens
  group by 2
)
select
  this_month.month,
  count(distinct user_id)
from monthly_activity this_month
left join monthly_activity last_month
  on this_month.user_id = last_month.user_id
  and this_month.month = last_month.month + interval '1 month'
join first_activity
  on this_month.user_id = first_activity.user_id
  and first_activity.month != this_month.month
where last_month.user_id is null
group by 1
```

Comment: You want `group by user_id` in the second CTE.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to update a couple other things, but got it to work.

Comment: In my case `GROUP BY TRUE` in place of `GROUP BY 1` [resolved](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/0cfd472ca68505c8cf5ebd90841127bf) it.